# Invoice Footer CSS getting lost in print while printng with Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, safari

I am creating Invoice sample in HTML. and after printing the same invoice.

The invoice print is fine when Printing with FireFox 
But when trying to print with Chrome  and Safari the Invoice footer getting lost its CSS setting.

I need a footer on last page at Bottom if more than one page in print.

**HTML :**

http://pastebin.com/A4q5HJN3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class=""><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/uwJjr">

<style class="cp-pen-styles">
/* Mostly: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ */

* {
        margin: 0;
}
html, body {
        height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
        margin-bottom: -142px;
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
        height: 142px;
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-wrap">
      <!-- Begin page content -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h1> Header </h1>
        </div>

                <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <h4>Service</h4>
            </th>
            <th>
              <h4>Description</h4>
            </th>
            <th>
              <h4>Hrs/Qty</h4>
            </th>
            <th>
              <h4>Rate/Price</h4>
            </th>
            <th>
              <h4>Sub Total</h4>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            <td>Article</td>
            <td><a href="#">Title of your article here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">-</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$200.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Template Design</td>
            <td><a href="#">Details of project here</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">10</td>
            <td class="text-right">75.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$750.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>
                   <tr>
            <td>Development</td>
            <td><a href="#">WordPress Blogging theme</a></td>
            <td class="text-right">5</td>
            <td class="text-right">50.00</td>
            <td class="text-right">$250.00</td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      <div id="push"></div>
    </div>

</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
</body></html>
```

**Print Sample**

[image]

Comment: Try doing this if you don't get any further help. Reduce the amount of code to the minimal amount possible that reproduces the problem: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @David but items can be long and more than 2 pages can be generated.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it on my Chrome browser and it seems ok. I'm pretty sure your problem lies with the following CSS

```
.page-wrap {
   min-height: 100%;
   /* equal to footer height */
   margin-bottom: -142px;
}

.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

Remove the content attribute and also remove the margin-bottom: -142px; from your page-wrap class. This seemed to be all ok for me.

Comment: With you solution same problem in chrome. Sample at http://oi58.tinypic.com/4hfwnp.jpg